# Getting "wrong addressing" error while trying to convert hexadecimal to ascii

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I am new on this language and trying to get familiar with it. In this example I'm getting a *"wrong addressing"* error, but what's wrong with it?

```
hextoasc proc near ; AX input, si point result storage address

push ax bx cx dx si di bp es
mov cx,00h
mov bx,0ah
hexloop1:

mov dx,0
div bx
add dl,'0'
push dx
inc cx
cmp ax, 0ah
jge hexloop1
add al, '0'
mov [si], al

hexloop2:

pop ax
inc si
mov [si], al
loop hexloop2
inc si
mov al, '$'
mov [si], al
pop es bp di si dx cx bx ax
ret

endp
```

This is my error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the fact it appears to be complaining about an addressing mode, it looks like it doesn't actually like the line:

```
push ax bx cx dx si di bp es
```

This is not actually a valid 8086 operation (the `push` and `pop` opcodes require *one* register) so, unless you have an assembler smart enough to break it out into individual instructions, you'll have to do it yourself:

```
push ax
push bx
push cx
push dx
push si
push di
push bp
push es

; all your other code goes here.

pop es
pop bp
pop di
pop si
pop dx
pop cx
pop bx
pop ax
```

Comment: Some assemblers (like FASM) do support PUSH/POP as multi-operand pseudo-ops, so you might occasionally come across examples of this syntax.

Comment: There is also PUSHA/POPA which pushes AX, CX, DX, BX, SP, BP, SI, DI in this order and pops them in reverse order (so they're restored correctly)

Comment: @Idloj, I think that was introduced later than the 8086. I vaguely remember doing some OS work *many* years ago and that instruction was rejected since it wasn't on all iterations of the chip.

Comment: You're right, I checked on Wikipedia and it was added on 80186. I thought it was 8086 because emu8086 list it in their documentation as part of the instruction set

Comment: Just checked the emu8086 doc again and it explicitly states that the instruction in only available since 80186. Embarrassing.